# Apache Camel Package Scan

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is it possible in Apache Camel config to provide multiple package scans? For an instance, can I provide this?

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.demo.package1</package>
    <package>com.demo.package2</package>
</camelContext>
```

Thanks,
NN

Comment: I believe so. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am new to Camel; hence, thought of putting the question here. Anyways, I got the answer. In document Camel guys have mentioned "... In Camel 2.0 this has been extended to allow selective inclusion and exclusion of discovered route classes using Ant like path matching. In spring this is specified by adding a <packageScan/> tag. The tag must contain one or more 'package' elements..." (http://camel.apache.org/spring.html). I am marking this thread closed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The Apache Camel documentation page:

http://camel.apache.org/spring.html

states, under the section entitled, "Using <packageScan>":

"Camel also provides a powerful feature that allows for the automatic discovery and initialization of routes in given packages. This is configured by adding tags to the camel context in your spring context definition, specifying the packages to be recursively searched for RouteBuilder implementations. To use this feature in 1.X, requires a  tag *specifying a comma separated list of packages that should be searched* e.g."

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <package>org.apache.camel.spring.config.scan.route</package>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to find route definations, you can use routeContext as a seperated xml file.
Here is the link : http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-import-routes-from-other-xml-files.html